# xml configuration for sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to take out the python sqlalchemy mappings from the model classes? Till now I was using Declarative mapping where the class will extend Declarative base. But now I want to map some models in a generated python module. So I can't modify the model classes.

1. Should I be using the classical mapper that is the mapper() function?
2. Does the classical mapping gives all the options as the declarative mapping?
3. Is there a xml configuration way like the hibernate hbm.xml files?

Regards,
Litty

Comment: The answers a "yes", "yes" and "no".  Perhaps you should ask for some more details or examples or something that is more helpful to solving your problem.  What part of the SQLAlchemy documentation is confusing?

Comment: This is a question during my initial investigation. Just wanted to confirm these from experts. My intent was to use xml based mapping if one is available; else make sure that whatever is possible with declarative is possible with classical as well.Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Check out the `autoload` argument to the `Table` constructor.  This is sort of equivalent to Hibernate's introspection feature, except that it's done at run-time instead of build-time.  It may help you.

Comment: @LItty: You really **should** update the question to explain what you really want to know.  It can't be trivial "yes", "yes", "no" kinds of things.  Was the SQLAlchemy documentation confusing in some way?  Was there parts that weren't clear?  Can you update the question to explain what part of the SQLAlchemy documentation confused you?

Answer (score 0):

Here a sample how to hand-craft your own solution for an xml-based orm class. It reads the User.hbm.xml-file from [this tutorial](http://www.allapplabs.com/hibernate/hibernate_comlete_example_hbm_files.htm). This is a hack - I don't know anything about Hibernate. Hope this fits your or maybe somebody elses understanding of your question.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                                                                 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-                                                                                                

import sqlalchemy as sqAl
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def generate_class(class_el):                                                                                          

    type_map = {'java.lang.String': sqAl.String,                                                                       
                'java.util.Date': sqAl.Date,                                                                           
                'java.lang.Double': sqAl.Float,                                                                        
                'java.lang.Long': sqAl.Integer}                                                                        

    dynclass_dict = {                                                                                                  
        'id': sqAl.Column(sqAl.Integer, primary_key=True),                                                             
        '__tablename__': class_el.attrib['table']                                                                      
        }                                                                                                              
    for field_el in class_el.findall('property'):                                                                      
        field = field_el.attrib                                                                                        
        if field['type'] in type_map:                                                                                  
            dynclass_dict[field['name']] = sqAl.Column(field['column'], type_map[field['type']])                       

    return type(class_el.attrib['table'].capitalize(), (declarative_base(sqAl.MetaData()),), dynclass_dict)            

classe = ET.parse('User.hbm.xml').getroot().find('class')
User = generate_class(classe)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # the two following lines create the table (if not already existing)                                                                                             
    engine = sqAl.create_engine('sqlite:///data.db', echo=True)                                                        
    User.__base__.metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=True)                                                         

    session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()                                                                              
    u = User(userFirstName="John F.", userLastName="Kennicknich", userName="jfk")                                      
    session.add(u)                                                                                                     
    session.commit()
```